# ATM Account Homework (Classes, Textfiles, Objects)

Tags: python, file, class, text, bank

I am completely lost. Our homework assignment is to:

1. Create an ATM Program that asks a user for their name and pin
2. Program will loop through asking user if they want to check balance, withdraw, deposit, or exit. You exit the loop when user selects exit. The initial balance is $10,000
3. Create a text file that records all transactions. First 2 lines of the file should be the User's name and Pin
4. Create a class called which includes the **init** and **str** functions to display info from the user(deposit, check balance, withdraw)
5. Program needs to read from the file and create an object. The fields for the object are the name, pin, and balance.
   6.If the pin number and the name they provide to not match the name and pin number for the BAcc object the program will end.  Otherwise you can proceeded to make as many transactions as you want updating the file
   7.Errors must by handled using try: blocks!  This includes both invalid data entry and insufficient funds on a withdraw.

This is the code I have right now, it doesn't do much but I just need a way to connect it.

```
accountfile=open("ATMACC.txt", "a")
name=input("What is your name? ")
pin=input("What is your Pin #? ")
accountfile.write("Name: " + name + "\n" + "PIN: " + pin + "\n")
USER_BALANCE = 10000
class BankAcc(object):
    def __init__(self,name,pin,balance):
        name = self.name
        pin = self.pin
        10000 = self.balance
    def __str__(self):
        return "Bank Account with Balance {}".format(self.name,self.balance)
    def checkbalance(self):
        print(self)
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.amount += amount
    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if self.balance > amount:
            self.balance -= amount
        else:
            raise ValueError
while True:
    answer=input("Would you like to deposit, withdraw, check balance, or exit? ")
    if answer=="deposit" or answer== "Deposit":
        x= input("How much would you like to deposit? ")
        USER_BALANCE += float(x)
        print ("Your new balance is: $" + str(USER_BALANCE))
        accountfile.write("\n" + "Deposit of $" + x + "." + " " + "Current balance is $" + str(USER_BALANCE))
        continue
    elif answer== "withdraw" or answer== "Withdraw":
        y= input("How much would you like to withdraw? ")
        if float (y)<=USER_BALANCE:
            USER_BALANCE -= float(y)
            print ("Your new balance is: $" + str(USER_BALANCE))
            accountfile.write("\n" + "Withdraw of $" + y + "." + " " + "Current balance is $" + str(USER_BALANCE))
            continue
        else:
            print ("Cannot be done. You have insufficient funds.")
    elif answer== "check balance" or answer== "Check Balance":
        print ("$" + str(USER_BALANCE))
    elif answer== "exit" or answer== "Exit":
        print ("Goodbye!")
        accountfile.close()
        break
    else:
        print ("I'm sorry, that is not an option")
```

Please help. I know this is a complete mess but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to explain what your mistakes are, I did what was asked.

```
class BankAcc(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pin, balance=10000.0): #If you want to give default balance if not provided explicitly do this
        self.name = name                    #variable where value is stored = expression
        self.pin = pin
        self.balance = balance
    def CheckUser(self, name, pin):       #A function to check wheather the user is valid or not
        try:
            if name != self.name or pin != self.pin:
                raise ValueError
            print("Name and Pin Matches")
        except ValueError:
            print("Name or Password is not correct")
            exit(0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}'s Bank Account with Balance {}".format(self.name, self.balance) #using only one substition in the string but providing 2 variables

    def checkbalance(self):
        return '$' + str(self.balance) #self is the instance of the class for printing balance use self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount        #self.ammount will create a new property but i think you want to increase your balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        try:                          #use try catct if raising an excpetion
            if self.balance >= amount:    #balance should be greater than and equal to the ammount 
                self.balance -= amount
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:                #Handle your exception 
                print("Cannot be done. You have insufficient funds.")

    def filedata(self):              #An extra function for writing in the file.
        return "{},{},{}".format(self.name,self.pin,self.balance)

accountfile = open("ATMACC.txt", "r+") #"r+" should be used becuase you are reading and writing
accountfiledata=accountfile.read().split(",")  #Can be done in the class it self
BankUser = BankAcc(accountfiledata[0],accountfiledata[1],float(accountfiledata[2])) #For simplicity i used comma seperated data and created an instance of it 
name=input("What is your name? ")
pin=input("What is your Pin #? ")
BankUser.CheckUser(name, pin)
#accountfile.write("Name: " + name + "\n" + "PIN: " + pin + "\n") #You did not specify that you want to write in file as well
#USER_BALANCE = 10000          it is not needed

while True:    #For multiple options use numbers instead of words such as 1 for deposit etc
    answer=input("Would you like to deposit, withdraw, check balance, or exit? ")
    if answer=="deposit" or answer== "Deposit":
        x= input("How much would you like to deposit? ")
        BankUser.deposit(float(x))   #use your deposit function
        print ("Your new balance is: " + BankUser.checkbalance())
        #continue  #Why using continue, no need for it
    elif answer== "withdraw" or answer== "Withdraw":
        y= input("How much would you like to withdraw? ")
        BankUser.withdraw(float(y))         #Use Your withdraw function why reapeating your self
    elif answer== "check balance" or answer== "Check Balance":
        print(BankUser.checkbalance())
    elif answer== "exit" or answer== "Exit":
        print ("Goodbye!")
        accountfile.close()
        exit(0)
    else:
        print ("I'm sorry, that is not an option")
    accountfile.seek(0)               #I dont know whether you want to record all tranction or a single one 
    accountfile.truncate()            #perform write function at the last
    accountfile.write(BankUser.filedata())
```

And text file format is ATMACC.txt

```
Himanshu,1111,65612.0
```